# ASP.NET MVC Razor Won't Accept My Valid Markup

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I like the Razor syntax a lot, but it certainly falls short of perfect. For example, I have the following block of markup.

```
@if (Model.FeaturedDestinations != null && Model.FeaturedDestinations.Count() > 0)
{
    int column = 0;

    foreach (var d in Model.FeaturedDestinations)
    {
        column++;
        if (column > 4)
        {
            </div>
            @{ column = 1; }
        }
        if (column == 1)
        {
            @:<div class="row-fluid">
        }
        <div class="span3">
            @RenderDestination(d)
        </div>
    }
    </div>
}
```

So, the editor gives me the squiggly lines indicating that I have an ending `<div>` tag before an opening one. I can live with that. But when I run the app, I actually get the following run-time error:

> Encountered end tag "div" with no matching start tag. Are your start/end tags properly balanced?

Obviously, I cannot live with that! So is there any trick for dealing with this case? I know what I'm doing as far as the markup I want. But Razor doesn't think so and it's taking over.

And why the heck is MVC wasting cycles checking for balanced tags?

Comment: I don't know... I searched a bit, and I found that someone else suggested the very same answer. ?

Comment: @gdoron: The same answer as what?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For reasons I don't understand, the following corrected the issue:

```
@if (Model.FeaturedDestinations != null && Model.FeaturedDestinations.Count() > 0)
{
    int column = 0;

    foreach (var d in Model.FeaturedDestinations)
    {
        column++;

        if (column > 4)
        {
            @:</div>
            column = 1;
        }

        if (column == 1)
        {
            @:<div class="row-fluid">
        }
        <div class="span3">
            @RenderDestination(d)
        </div>
    }
    @:</div>
}
```

Note the addition of `@:` before several tags. I don't know why these are necessary--the Razor highlighting indicated that it recognized these were tags and not code.

Also, why did this make the error go away? The thing that caused the run-time error has not changed. Perhaps someone can fill in the blanks for me.

Comment: I think the syntax that works is actually much more readable, and apparently Razor agrees ;)  Razor sometimes gets confused.  That's why the escape sequences like this exist.

Comment: I also sometimes get confused. :) If it's a Razor issue, then why was it generating run-time errors. That just makes no sense to me.

Comment: @JonathanWood Thanks for answer. But in visual studio If I press ctrl + k + D to align code, It's reformatting it as @: (</div> is moving to next line). So causing again same error

Comment: @RahulNikate: Yep, Razor gets a little confused in some cases.

Answer (score 7):

You need to add @: in front of the  tag (as identified in the marked answer). This blog entry explains the reason for that:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/15/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax.aspx

From the blog:

> One of the techniques that Razor uses to implicitly identify when a
>   code block ends is to look for tag/element content to denote the
>   beginning of a content region.

and

> Not all content container blocks start with a tag element tag, though,
>   and there are scenarios where the Razor parser can’t implicitly detect
>   a content block.
>
> Razor addresses this by enabling you to explicitly indicate the
>   beginning of a line of content by using the @: character sequence
>   within a code block.  The @: sequence indicates that the line of
>   content that follows should be treated as a content block: