# end tag "text" with no matching start tag

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor-pages

My code looks like this.

```
@{
    if( results.Count() > 0 )
    { 
        <text><ul class="list-group"></text>
        foreach( var part in results )
        {
            <text><li><a href="#">@part["pgwName"]</a></li></text>
        }
        <text></ul></text>
    }
}
```

I'm getting this error on `<text></ul></text>`.

> Parser Error Message: Encountered end tag "text" with no matching start tag.  Are your start/end tags properly balanced?

So, if Razor doesn't consider this valid, how do I put the closing tag for the list in?

Note:
Not a duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC Razor Won't Accept My Valid Markup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10610344/asp-net-mvc-razor-wont-accept-my-valid-markup) as it doesn't use the `<text>` tag.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10610344/asp-net-mvc-razor-wont-accept-my-valid-markup

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like `<text>` tag is not necessary here
You can do something like that(without `<text>` at all)

```
if( results.Count() > 0 )
{ 
    <ul class="list-group">
        @foreach( var part in results )
        {
            <li><a href="#">@part["pgwName"]</a></li>
        }
    </ul>
}
```

Comment: Yeah, <text> is really just useful in places such as Javascript code